# vim74 with PyExc_OSError when importing python3 module

Tags: python-3.x, vim

I have compiled vim with python3 support.
But when I type `vim -c 'python3 import logging'` in the bash, the vim can't execute the command correctly.

```
Error detected while processing command line:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, io, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/time.cpython-34m.so: undefined
 symbol: PyExc_OSError
```

I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out! You can check this problem in vim more correctly by doing:

```
:python3 import time
```

The problem stems from the Python 3 build, caused by not enabling shared libraries. You can check if you have this problem:

```
vim$ python3 -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CONFIG_ARGS'])"
'--prefix=/u/home/j/joelfred/opt' '--enable-shared' '--enable-big-digits' '--enable-ipv6' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/u/home/j/joelfred/opt/lib/pkgconfig:'
```

Notice I have `--enable-shared` as a result. If this isn't there, you will need to recompile Python 3. I would recommend using the options that show up here, and adding `--enable-shared`. Once recompiled, you shouldn't have any problems.